# Determining domain and range with inverse function

Tags: functions

$$f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x+2$$
In this function,i have to calculate the domain and range as well as its inverse function.

I have tried to do in this way:

Let $p=(\frac{1-x}{1+x})$.

After some calculations, I found that $f(p)=\frac{3+p}{p+1}$.
This shows the domain must be all real numbers except $(-1)$
Is it correct or not?

Comment: Use mathjax formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes mate,you are right About the domain it's$\mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$
And range is $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$

The inverse function$f^{-1}:$$\mathbb{R}-\{1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{1\} $such that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{3-x}{x-1}$

Comment: well i calculated that the domain would be all real number except(-1) but you wrote all real number except 1.

Comment: Sorry , forget to input the $(-)$ sign.see the answer if it's okay..

Comment: Yeah,now it is ok